# OKTA Saml 2.0 configurations

Tags: single-sign-on, okta, saml-2.0

I have created a SAML 2.0 App on okta and have finished all the configurations. The app(service provide) and authentication seems to work fine. But I still have this notification on the SSO tab of the app on OKTA. I am just worried if this means some of the settings are not complete and if I am missing something.

If somebody can confirm that OKTA doesn't update these settings or point me to what I am missing, I will be greatful.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're integration is working, don't worry about this notification. If it's not, you may want to check out the SAML tracer add-in for Firefox as I've found this invaluable in debugging similar integration issues.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/

Comment: Benjamin I am using saml tracer and everything seems to work perfectly. Just want to make sure that this warning can be ignore with confidence and will not have any effect on security.

Comment: Coming from "Head of Platform at Okta" I can now be sure that I can really ignore this notification ;)